# Background Image not working in Ionic/Javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

My background image is not working for this ionic project in css. It works if I inline it into the HTML but its sloppy. I remember hearing something about base64 but not sure. does anybody know what the problem could be? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide a snippet of code so we can understand what you are trying to say by "inline it into the html". My understanding of that was you are writing the style within the tag itself in the html file rather then a cs file.

Answer (score 0):

put the images you want to use within the project in www/img folder and then set the style of it in your html file.

**for example:**

```
 <ion-content  style="background: url(img/image_name.jpg) center; background-size: cover;">
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution he is looking for because he says it already works for him when he in-lines the image.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I currently have. When I add the background image to the element(css) it doesn't work. @deltashade

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your image file path is wrong. Did you try both: from your `www` into the `img` folder & from your `css` folder into the `img` folder like:

```
www/img/myImage.png
```

or

```
../img/myImage.png
```

Hint: when you include something in your App you have to think that your root folder is `www`